# (Bootstrap) Vue Datepicker: How to define start and end date, so that the end date can't be before the start date?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, datepicker, bootstrap-vue

I have two BootstrapVue datepickers in my form in Vue.js. I'd like to implement a holiday manager, so you can define the start (input-3) and end date (input-4) of your holiday. The end date should be greater or equal to the start date. My current implementation looks as follows:

```
<b-form-group
      id="input-group-3"
      label="Anfangsdatum:"
      label-for="input-3"
>
<b-form-datepicker
      id="input-3"
      v-model="von"
      placeholder="Anfangsdatum auswählen"
      required
      :min="minAnfang"
></b-form-datepicker>
</b-form-group>

<b-form-group id="input-group-4" label="Enddatum:" label-for="input-4">
<b-form-datepicker
     id="input-4"
     v-model="bis"
     placeholder="Enddatum auswählen"
     :min="minEnde"
     required
></b-form-datepicker>
</b-form-group>
```

The data part in Vue is implemented as follows:

```
  data() {
    const datum = new Date();
    const datum_heute = new Date(datum.getFullYear(), datum.getMonth(), datum.getDate());
    
    const minVon = new Date(datum_heute);
    minVon.setDate(minVon.getDate()+ 1);

    const minBis = new Date(datum_heute);
    minBis.setDate(minVon.getDate()+1);

    return {
        Urlaubsart: "",
        Grund: "",
        von: "",
        bis: "",
        Status: "",
        BenutzerID: 24,
        minAnfang: minVon,
        minEnde: minBis,
      arten: [
        { value: null, text: "Wählen Sie die Urlaubsart aus" },
        { value: "Urlaub", text: "Urlaub" },
        { value: "Sonderurlaub", text: "Sonderurlaub" },
      ],
      gruende: [
        { value: "Umzug", text: "Umzug" },
        { value: "Hochzeit", text: "Hochzeit" },
        { value: "Geburt", text: "Geburt" },
        { value: "Umzug", text: "Sonstiges" },
      ],
      Urlaubstage: "",
    };
  }
```

So how can I ensure, that the end date is equal to the start date or greater?

Comment: One option is to make the end date a computed property with get/set as described here: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-Setter During set you can check the input and compare with start date. Even better: do the check in the get, when the start date changes, end date will also change.

Comment: Could you please provide a code snippet? I don't really understand how you mean it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've created a codepen for you: https://codepen.io/mtveerman/pen/gOwwNoL
(note that I use vuetify as the layout engine, but you'll get the idea)

What I did:

- Define an `internalBis` property
- Define a computed `bis` property with a `get` and `set` function:
- Set the `internalBis` property in the `set` function
- Compare `von` and `internalBis` in the `get` function, return `von` if `internalBis` is smaller than `von`

In your components and form submissions you should only work with `bis`, since that will always return the correct value. Note that if `von` now changes to a date after the original `bis`, `bis` is automatically changing as well.

For you, the most interesting code is this:

```js
data: () => ({
     von: new Date().toISOString().substr(0, 10),
     internalBis: new Date().toISOString().substr(0, 10)
  }),
  computed: {
    bis: {
      // getter
      get: function () {
        if (this.internalBis < this.von) {
          return this.von
        }
        return this.internalBis
      },
      // setter
      set: function (newValue) {
        this.internalBis = newValue
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: I get an Error in render: "InternalError: too much recursion". I removed the bis property from data and added it to computed. I also removed the minBis property and minEnde. The code looks as follows: `computed: {
    bis: {
      get: function () {
        if (this.bis < this.von) {
          return this.von
        }
        return this.bis
      },
      set: function(newValue) {
        this.bis = newValue
      }
    }
  }`

Comment: No, look at my code. There is a reason I use `internalBis`. You cannot set `this.bis` in the setter since that will recursively call the setter.

Comment: Okay, thank you! Now it works, so when I select a von date than the bis date is equal to the von date, but it is still possible to select a bis date, that is before the von date..

Comment: Well, you'll need to play with the `:min` properties, for example by setting it to `:min="von"`, or create another computed property for this, where you return `von` + 1 day.

Comment: I've updated the codepen to show you the principle.